# Log error out whole record details in log file

Tags: apex

I am performing inset operation on some records and, here I want to log the error out record details in log file. Basically i want to find out error out records from -  list<Database.SaveResult> resultSet object. Kindly find the below code for more details on this requirement.

```
list<Database.SaveResult> resultSet = Database.Insert(ListObject,false);
for (Database.SaveResult sr : resultSet) {
for(Database.Error err : sr.getErrors()) {
System.debug(err.getFields());
}
}
```

In the log currently getting empty round braces only. I am expecting all the field values which got error out.

I can see this behavior in the data loader tools error and success file where I can find the whole record in error file and the error message at the end.

Comment: getErrors() returns an array of one or more database error objects providing the error code and description, if error occurs . If no error occurred, then it returns an empty set. Are you sure your DML is running into an error? Put the inner for loop inside this IF condition and test it out: if(!sr.isSuccess()){ <Place getErrors code here>}

Comment: there is no `System.log` method in the doc??

Comment: Sorry it is System.debug(). Yes I am sure that it will generate error.

Comment: Moreover I am getting the error code and description but here I want is the record details. Consider I have list of A to Z characters and I got error to insert character K then I want the details about record/object K.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to serialize the record from your `List<SObject>`. Nothing from the `SaveResult` will help you here. There are a couple ways that would work, but for `insert` the `Id` will be `null`, so you should prefer an index approach.

```
for (Integer i = 0; i < resultSet.size(); i++)
{
    if (!resultSet[i].getErrors().isEmpty())
    {
        SObject errorRecord = records[i];
        String logResult = JSON.serialize(errorRecord.getPopulatedFieldsAsMap());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the update. But how we can make sure that the index of the record is the same which is error out.

Comment: The save results are in the same order as the records...

Comment: Yes Perfect. It means it will persist the DML operation order, but now I am trying to extract the error out results and I am not able to get the error details using - errorRecord.getStatusCode() and errorRecord.getMessage().